# Classification of indecomposable inclusions $(H \subset G)$ with $G$ decomposable

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups, computational-group-theory, tag-removed

*Definition*: A group $G$ is  **indecomposable**  if:  $G = G_1 \times G_2 \Rightarrow \exists i \ G_i = 1$.

We can generalize the notion of indecomposable from groups to inclusion of groups as follows:

*Definition*: Two inclusions of finite groups are equivalent, $(A \subset B) \sim (C \subset D)$, if: $(A/A_B \subset B/A_B) \simeq (C/C_D \subset D/C_D)$ with $A_B$ the [normal core](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/908033/84284) of $A$ in $B$.
 *Remark*: The equivalence class of $(A \subset B)$ is the same that the conjugacy class of a transitive permutation group $G$ (see [this GAP Data Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Datalib/trans.html)) with $(A \subset B) \sim (G_1 \subset G)$.

*Definition*: An inclusion of groups $(H \subset G)$ is **indecomposable** if (for $H_i \le G_i)$: $(H \subset G) \sim (H_1 \times H_2 \subset G_1 \times G_2)$ $\Rightarrow$  $\exists i \ H_i = G_i$
 *Examples*: The maximal inclusions are indecomposable.

In the maximal (finite index) case, $(H \subset G)$ is indecomposable **and** $G$ decomposable if and only if
$(H \subset G) \sim (D_S \subset S \times S)$ with $S$ a nonabelian finite simple group and $D_S$ the diagonal subgroup.
It's proved by the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/914095/84284). Are there others examples beyond the maximal case?

**Question**: What's the classification of indecomposable inclusions $(H \subset G)$ with $G$ decomposable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood the definition of an indecomposable inclusion correctly, then any core-free subgroup $H$ of a direct product $G=G_1 \times G_2$ in which $H$ is indecomposable, and is not contained in any direct factor of $G$ isomorphic to $G_1$ and $G_2$ will be an example.

There are many such examples, such as $G=S_3 \times S_3$ with $H$ a diagonal subgroup of order $2$, $3$, or $6$.

Comment: It seems to be essentially a *diagonal* phenomenon. If $G_1$ and $G_2$ have no isomorphic (non-trivial) subgroup then an indecomposable subgroup $H$ of $G_1 \times G_2$ is contained in one direct factor. Then we could reduce the classification to the classification of  $(H \subset K^n)$ with $H$ core-free and $H \le D_K$ with $D_K$ the whole diagonal subgroup of $K^n$, isn't it?

Comment: About the choice of this long definition, what is not clear to me is the existence of a core-free decomposable inclusion $(H \subset G)$ which is (then) $\sim (H_1 \times H_2 \subset G_1 \times G_2)$ but $\not = (H'_1 \times H'_2 \subset G'_1 \times G'_2)$  (with $H'_i < G'_i$).

Comment: About the first comment: "$G_1$ and $G_2$ have no isomorphic (non-trivial) subgroup" means that $1 \neq K_i \le G_i$ implies that $K_1 \not\simeq K_2$.

Comment: The first sentence of your first comment is correct if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are both finite, because then they must have coprime order, but not in general. For example, the (additive) group ${\mathbb Z}_4 \oplus {\mathbb Z}$ has infinite cyclic subgroups that are not contained in either factor.

Comment: Thank you for this information. In fact I'm mainly interested in the classification for finite groups.